# Set of Equations Form a One Dimensional Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm studying for a differential geometry midterm and am stuck on what should be a pretty simple question. It asks for the solution to a system of equations as a one dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R} ^3. $ They are $$ x + y + z  = 1 $$ and $$ x^4 +y ^4 + z ^4 = 3 $$

I get that there is 1 degree of freedom, so it makes sense that is is 1 dimensional, and I know the Hausdorff and countability condition for manifolds, but it seems like there's a theorem about sub-manifolds I am forgetting?

Would I prove it using some immersion or something from a compact set, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1256280/is-c-x-y-mid-x3-xy-y3-c-subset-mathbbr2-an-embedded-sub) , but the inclusion is not clear to me.

Comment: Do you know transverality?

Comment: I have a vague understanding, but it is not  covered in the class notes. I am using the professors notes which they assigned instead of a textbook

Comment: Have you folks learned to apply the implicit function theorem? This is the case where you have a mapping $F\colon\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2$, and you're looking at $F^{-1}\big((1,3)\big)$. Does the derivative matrix have rank $2$ at every point of that set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt at a solution is to compute the Jacobian as
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
4x^3 & 4y^3 & 4z^3 
\end{bmatrix}
which is rank 2 because all the variables being zero is not a solution to the system. Also if x,y,z are the cube root are $ 1/4 $ they don't satisfy the system.  This means I can use Regular Value Theorem ( which I think is what Ted Shifrin meant by applying Implicit Value Theorem ) to say that the dimension of the level set is 1 and that it is a submanifold.

I think I have covered everything now.

Comment: Not correct just yet. The matrix has rank $1$ if the second row becomes a scalar multiple of the first row. Can that happen in your case?

Comment: @TedShifrin, no because it doesn't satisfy the system, thanks